# Error while installing pip install apache-superset

Tags: installation, pip, apache-superset

```
TypeError: CCompiler_spawn() got an unexpected keyword argument 'env'
        [end of output]

        note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      error: metadata-generation-failed

      Encountered error while generating package metadata.

      See above for output.

      note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
      hint: See above for details.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error when using Python 3.10. Apache-Superset currently only supports Python 3.8 and 3.9: https://pypi.org/project/apache-superset/

Comment: Tq its working in 3.9,  but facing issue in while using the command "superset db upgrade"

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\ACER\Virtual_environment\venv\Scripts\superset.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'superset'